# missing package in update manager foomatic-filters_4.0.16-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

Tags: package-management

Get this message when I try to update my stuff. Says I have a bad internet connection but I have a nice fiber line here :-) I belive its missing on the webserver. Is there anyone who can put it there for me. Message says "Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/foomatic-filters/foomatic-filters_4.0.16-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.163 80]"

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `sudo apt-get update` first; the package was recently updated and the old version is no longer available:

```
http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/foomatic-filters/foomatic-filters_4.0.16-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```